# I need ps4 help purchased unauthorized games?

Tags: ps4

Can u return downloads....?    My son took his grandmother's card without permission and used it.  It totaled $470 ...   please can I fix this.

Thank you

Comment: Hi, you'll need to speak to Playstation support on this one. Arqade is a community help site, and has no ability to interact with the systems at PlayStation. https://support.us.playstation.com/ is what you need.

Comment: Also, while speaking to Sony's customer service, in addition to asking for the money back you should also ensure the credit card number is removed from your son's account.

Answer (score 5):

You will have to contact the official Sony Support team. https://support.us.playstation.com/articles/en_US/KC_Article/Requesting-a-PlayStation-Store-Refund#sect1 explains how to do this.

Next up, you will probably want to remove the payment method from your PSN account so he can't do it again, set up a password for purchases (both are explained in the linked article). and thoroughly explain to your son that what he did was wrong. If you need advice on what to tell him and what punishments would be appropriate, there is a [parenting stack exchange](https://parenting.stackexchange.com/) on this very site that will be able to help you with this (as this is off-topic for our site).

Answer (score 0):

Well Bobbi, from my experience with PS4 you cannot return anything that was downloaded on the store. Your best bet would be to contact PS4 Customer Service and try and talk something out with them

A bit of parenting advice as well? Maybe don't allow your son any contact with money for a while. As a middle-class citizen of America if my child were to spend $470 I would immediately ground him, and sell all of his toys and game systems until I got my money back. Maybe that's the approach you should take with your son?

Best wishes, God Bless
            - Stradivix